# How to count model years in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am pulling a running list of data on customer interest in vehicles. I specifically want to be able to count the Model Years of interest to see who is interested in 2019/20 new vehicles vs everything older.

The issue at hand is that 2020 and 2019 are counted when I CountIf for "*20*" + CountIf for "*19*".

Most data in the set will come through in the form of "2019 Lamborghini Aventador" or "2017 Ford Fusion" or sometimes "20 Nissan Titan".

The difficulty is with "20" being in almost every model year. So I don't want everything counted that way. Also, if I don't have a model year in four digits, some counts won't show up as they don't have anything for the first asterisk in "*20*" to be usable. Nothing isn't an optional variable it seems.

The current list has the following model years:

```
2019
2009
2007
2018
17
2019
2019
2020
```

So what I'll ultimately need is "New" count 4 and a separate code will return "Used" count of 3.

Ive done CountIf + CountIf (returned 10)
CountIFs (returned 3, since only 3 have "20" and "19")
DCountA (returned 0)

Comment: There's private customer data so I can't share the sheet.

Comment: Imagine a column has 2019 Nissan Titan, 2017 Hyundai Sonata, 19 Ford Fusion, etc.

Comment: Perhaps this ended up in the wrong category on this site, but I'm using Google Sheets functions.

Comment: nope, you are on the right place

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(
 IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))=2, 
   "20"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"), 
        REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

## for 2019/2020:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"2019/2020", SUM(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(
 IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))=2, 
   "20"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"), 
        REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1", 0), 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1 matches '2019|2020'", 0))})
```

[image: 0]

---

## for the rest (eg. 2018 - 2000)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"the rest", SUM(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(
 IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))=2, 
   "20"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"), 
        REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1", 0), 
 "select Col2 
  where not Col1 matches '2019|2020'", 0))})
```

[image: 0]

---

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Oncwd-9KUK0PVX5HV6AKpLuUnQwvBITAtHhKofEwaQ/edit#gid=1596759942)